# Dockerfile - parameterized FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to include arguments in the `FROM` section. Is this possible? In the `Dockerfile`, I have:

```
ARG VERSION
FROM tomcat:$VERSION
```

I build as following:

```
docker build --build-arg VERSION=8.0 .
```

I get the following error:

```
Please provide a source image with `from` prior to commit
```

I am using docker version 1.12.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker 1.9 [has added support for build time arguments](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#190-2015-11-03).

[Reason](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/use-arg-dockerfile-dynamic-image-specification) for the error

Comment: Any idea why it is not working on my side? I am using Docker version 1.12.6.

Comment: it does not support ARG

Comment: if you want to use ARG, install latest stable docker version

Comment: I will try that out.

Comment: (SUPPORTED VERSION)[https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/#17050-ce-2017-05-04]

Comment: The answer is really that you need Docker 17.05 or later to use an ARG as a FROM argument: "But until recently (Docker's 17.05 release, to be precise), you weren't able to use an ARG to specify all or part of your Dockerfile's mandatory FROM command."